# Errors trying to create reusable form component in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using the Angular Material Select and it's working well:

```
<div [formGroup]="dwellingValues">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" hideRequiredMarker>
  <mat-label>Dwelling Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="typeofDwelling">
    <mat-option>Please Select</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let dwellingType of dwellingOptions.dwellingTypes" [value]="dwellingType">
      {{dwellingType}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Because I have a large number of these, I'm trying to create a reusable component.

I've created the following:

```
export class MySelectComponent {
  @Input() formControl: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() items: string[];

  constructor() { }

}
```

With the following html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" hideRequiredMarker>
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder=placeholder formControlName=formControl>
    <mat-option>Please Select</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
      {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="dwellingValues">
    <app-my-select [label]="'Dwelling Type'"  [formControl]="'typeofDwelling'" [items]="dwellingOptions.dwellingTypes" ></app-my-select>         
</div>
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the FormControlName as the input not the formControl.You need to get the formControl and Pass it as input.

parent html as

```
<div [formGroup]="dwellingValues">
 <app-my-select 
  [label]="'Dwelling Type'" 
  [selectFormControl]="typeofDwelling" 
  [items]="dwellingOptions.dwellingTypes">
 </app-my-select>
</div>
```

best practice is using getter for formControl.
parent html as

```
<div [formGroup]="dwellingValues">
 <app-my-select [label]="'Dwelling Type'" [formControl]="typeofDwelling" [items]="dwellingOptions.dwellingTypes" ></app-my-select>         
</div>
```

and in parent controller.ts

```
public get typeofDwelling(): FormControl {
return this.dwellingValues.get('typeofDwelling') as FormControl;
}
```

and change formControl input type as FormControl

```
export class MySelectComponent {
 @Input() selectFormControl: FormControl;
 @Input() label: string;
 @Input() items: string[];

 constructor() { }

}
```

and child html as

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" hideRequiredMarker>
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="selectFormControl">
    <mat-option>Please Select</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
        {{item}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

here is a demo of this [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reusable-fom-control)

Comment: Actually, it seems to work, but in the console I'm getting No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Comment: can you check the demo and make the relevant changes(added the editor url of demo)